# How to make background video 100vh-navbar on all devices while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, video

I created this homepage recently for a client:
https://www.calklin.com/

I was able to make the video responsive by following this guide:
https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-video/

However I have yet not been able to find a way to keep the video responsive, while being 100vh-61px to take the navbar into consideration and maintaining the correct aspect ratio.

Grateful for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're on the right track. Just that you don't seem to have whitespaces in your calc() function for the height. Just change this

```
.background-video {
    height: calc(100vh-61px) !important;
}
```

To this

```
.background-video {
    height: calc(100vh - 61px) !important;
}
```

### You can read more about the need for adding whitespaces inside the calc() function on the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), under the notes section.

### EDIT

If you want to maintain the aspect ratio of the video and make it responsive accordingly, you might want to use this instead

```
.background-video {
    height: calc(100% - 61px) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The property was actually set like this intentionally as it messes up the aspect ratio while activated. I corrected the rule for now, but as you can see the background video now unfortuantely doesn't scale properly,

Comment: Also the padding-top rule: 56.25 % (to maintain the ascept ratio) as recommended by the guide of fluid width above quits working after the calculation.

Comment: I guess the edit that I added to the post, should do the trick.

Comment: Now on further notice, I still do think your problem persists. The aspect ratio of the video wont let you display it in the same ratio perserving the navbar at the same time on a 1920x1080 screen. The bottom of the video gets cut off when you try and maintain the aspect ratio, as the space in there is more like 17:9, because of the navbar eating away 61px, while the video is only 16:9. If I do manage to find a solution, I'll edit it in here, and let you know. I believe with bigger screens, to maintain the ratio you'd need to put white bars on the left and right of the video, maybe.

Comment: I believe that your recent edit didn't make it into the post, it's referring to the height. Please check. Many thanks for helping out, I'm not sure if it's possible either but if it is it would be amazing.

Comment: If you maintain the aspect ratio, and want to prevent the nav-bar, then the result would look something like this. https://i.imgur.com/BYoihdR.png

Comment: Are you interested in that look? Any device that's smaller (that is less than 1214px in my test) would obviously work just fine without the borders on the left and right.

Comment: Yes could be a solution. I'm also thinking about an alternative solution: what if I make the background video 100vh and give the navbar an absolute position with a higher z index to float on top of the 100vh not taking up any space? There's not really any important content displayed in the 61 px top of the video anyway.

Comment: Or is there a solution where the video scales down when the window shrinks? The most important thing is that the whole video is visible when resizing the window, so nothing is cut off.